# While conditional loop in Python

Tags: while-loop, conditional-statements

I am writing a simple book recommender function in Python that takes in an answer and recommends a book called "Undoctored". In the code below, when the input is equal to "None", the loop still gives me the last answer of "Interesting read." What is wrong with my while loop?

```
def recommend_book():
    current_book = input("What book are you reading currently? ")
    while input != "Undoctored":
      if input == "None":
        return("Go pick up a book!")
      else:    
        return(f'"{current_book}" is an interesting read. I also recommend "Undoctored" by Dr. William Davis.')
```

I also tried adding "break" after the first if statement and that still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have said, you are calling input but need to call current_book. Try this code:

```
def recommend_book():
    current_book = input("What book are you reading currently? ")
    while current_book != "Undoctored":
      if current_book == "None":
        return(print("Go pick up a book!"))
      else:    
        return(print(f'"{current_book}" is an interesting read. I also recommend "Undoctored" by Dr. William Davis.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the variables you're using!

`current_book = input("What book are you reading currently?")`

This line of code sets a variable named `current_book`, and the value of that variable is whatever the user inputs.

Your next lines of code, though, are:

```
while input != "Undoctored":
      if input == "None":
...
```

Specifically, `while input != "Undoctored":` isn't checking for what the variable `current_book` is, it's checking for what the variable `input` is. Since `input` is a standard function, it is certainly not equal to "None". :)

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you :D